# How to report on the performance of dynamic subject lines?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, dataextensions

I have dynamic subject lines being pulled in from a Data Extension. I then have a code snippet content block that has a set of if statements which determine what row/subject line the recipient should get. I then place `%%=ContentBlockbyId("147137")=%%` in the subject line section referencing the code snippet content block.

Is it possible to report on the performance of each subject line? How would I do this? All reports and export options just show `%%=ContentBlockbyId("147137")=%%` as the subject line.

My first thought is to use impression regions but I'm not entirely sure how to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution I think would be to put a field in your Sendlog called 'Subjectline' or whatever your AMPscript variable is named in the content area you use to create your dynamic subject line. This should store the final subject for each send inside your send log.

From there you can use JobID, SubscriberID, Subject, etc. to match for any other tracking information via SQL Query Activity to gather your reporting.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an ampscript code in the email to log the jobid, subscriberkey and subject line to a DE at send time and use SQL query to join on jobid to a data view for reporting. I haven't tested this code but you will get the idea

```
%%[ 

if _isTestSend == false and _messagecontext == "SEND" then 
    InsertDE("LogDE", "jobid", _jobid, "subscriberkey", _subscriberkey, "subjectline", ContentBlockbyId("147137")) 
endif 

]%%
```

Open data view: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_open.htm&type=5

Comment: Why do this when you can do Send Logging as @Gortonington suggested?

Comment: I think both are valid solutions however, assuming the log is just needed for a specific dynamic email, sendlog will store sends from all email sends and not from a specific email which will require further filtering down to get logs for a specific email sends.